# fish shell command subsitution in watch command

Tags: shell, terminal, fish

I'm trying to use the watch command in the fish shell.

```
sudo watch -d "lsof -a -p (pidof myprogram)"
```

As you can see this valid command substitution syntax for fish. however I get the following error in `watch` when I run it.

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('
sh: -c: line 0: `lsof -a -p (pidof myprogram)'
```

If I change the command to sh compatible syntax

```
sudo watch -d "lsof -a -p $(pidof myprogram)"
```

I get the following error.

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(pidof)'.                                                                                                                        
fish: sudo watch -d "lsof -a -p $(pidof myprogram)"
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why `fish` should care about data that looks like another language's syntax. Issue a warning, sure, in case the user expected command substitution occur, but treat it as an error?

Comment: This is a syntax error because `$()` is invalid syntax. It is that because otherwise people would try `$()` and get commands *executed* with literal `$()`, so it's safer to tell them that what they are most likely trying wouldn't work. The way around it is to single-quote it, like you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

```
sudo watch -d "lsof -a -p "(pidof myprogram)
```

I.e. exit the quotes and do the command substitution (without a space in-between, so it'll be directly attached).

There's a bit of a gap in here in that you want the command's output to not be split at all - here it would split it on newline, and make multiple tokens like `"lsof -a -p "line1 "lsof -a -p"line2`. That shouldn't be an issue in this case, but if you want it, you should use `string split0` like

```
 sudo watch -d "lsof -a -p "(pidof myprogram | string split0)
```

which will only split on NULL-bytes, which aren't allowed in commandline arguments (this is a general unix thing - because arguments to `main` are passed as NULL-delimited strings without any other indication of length, if they contain NULLs they will be truncated).

Answer (score 2):

`watch` will use `sh` to execute a shell command. You can single-quote the string to prevent `fish` from panicking over data intended for a different shell.

```
sudo watch -d 'lsof -a -p $(pidof myprogram)'
```